# How to test with rspec a returned exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

```
  def show
begin
  @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
  authorize(@cart)
  @cart_entries = CartEntry.where(:cart_id => @cart.id)
  @products = {}
  @pr_references = {}
  @cart_entries.each do |cart_entry|
    @pr_references[cart_entry.id] = Reference.find(cart_entry.reference_id)
    @products[cart_entry.id] = Product.find(@pr_references[cart_entry.id].product_id)
  end
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: {'error': e}, status: :not_found}
  end
end
```

I want to test when Cart.find() doesn't find the cart and I want to test the method return a 404 HTTP code with the test below.

```
 it 'don\'t find cart, should return 404 error status' do
  delete :destroy, params: {id: 123, format: 'json'}

  expect(response).to have_http_status(404)
end
```

Have you got some indications or solution to do that ?
I'm a nooby with ruby on rails, if you have some tips with the code I posted I'll take it.

Thank you :)

Comment: What is the output of your current test?

Comment: The output is Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError: Api::V1::CartsController

  0) Api::V1::CartsController GET #show don't find cart, return 404 error status
     Failure/Error: get :show, params: {id: 123, format: 'json'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems some other code is raising an exception before your `Cart.find` statement is executed. For this reason, the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception is never risen, and it is never captured by the `rescue` block.

Based on the exception that is raising, it seems you are using [Pundit gem](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) for dealing with authorization. The authorization rules offered by this gem are surely running before your `show` method starts. Probably this is happening as a consequence of a [before_filter](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter) statement, either in this controller or in a parent controller.

You will need to handle this kind of errors in your application. It may be handy to use a [rescue_form](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from) statement in a base controller that is inherited by all other controllers, so that you don't have to deal with this kind of errors in every controller.

Comment: I put rescue_from my exception into the ApplicationController and that works now. Thank for your help